# SQL Server DB_mail sending multiple counts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sp-send-dbmail

I am using `db_mail` in SQL Server 2008 r 2 to send counts of mail daily.

How can I send 1 email daily that has 3 counts ( Count A, Count B, Count C) included?

Comment: Please share related code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query with multiple columns as you want.

> - [`[ @query = ] 'query'`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)
>
>   Is a query to execute. *The results of the query can be attached as a **file**, or included in the **body*** of the e-mail message. The query is of type `nvarchar(max)`, and can contain any valid Transact-SQL statements. Note that the query is executed in a separate session, so local variables in the script calling sp_send_dbmail are not available to the query.

Sample query:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Adventure Works Administrator',
    @recipients = 'danw@Adventure-Works.com',
    @query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) As CountA, 1 As CountB, 2 As CountC
                  FROM AdventureWorks2012.Production.WorkOrder
                  WHERE DueDate > ''2004-04-30''
                  AND  DATEDIFF(dd, ''2004-04-30'', DueDate) < 2' ,
    @subject = 'Work Order Count',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
```

---

You can also use a variable to set in the body.

Comment: Thanks. I created a stored procedure and executed the sp using the @query to email the desired results